# How do I type a dot(.) on top of an alphabet in HTML?

Tags: css, html

A dot on top of an variable means its derivative with time. I want to type this in a HTML page. How do I do that??

PS-essentially the equivalent of \dot{x} in latex.

Comment: You need a Unicode character with a dot ! ... As simple as that

Comment: @AbdelrahmanElkady I couldn't find one. I need it for many alphabets.I could find double dots for vowels but that doesn't help much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[MathJax](http://www.mathjax.org/) can to that for you :)

or even you can use a simple script to change your text in to an image using this:

http://www.codecogs.com/latex/integration/htmlequations.php

using the script above you can get this:

[http://latex.codecogs.com/svg.latex?\dot{x}](http://latex.codecogs.com/svg.latex?%5Cdot%7Bx%7D)

and these are all latex codes you may need:

http://web.ift.uib.no/Teori/KURS/WRK/TeX/symALL.html

Comment: Woah! That is a full-fledged math package! I was actually hoping to get some thing simpler like a unicode number. I will give this a try and if I don't get anything simpler, I will accept your answer. Thanks a lot @Afshin

Comment: Hi @Afshin The cogehogs image does not compile latex properly. I get a dot to the side and not on top.

Comment: It does not happen to me? I gave:  `<span lang="latex" style="background-color: white;">\cdot{x}</span> `. Does not happen for $\cdot{x}$ as well. Please see here:  [IMG]http://i62.tinypic.com/5bzls7.jpg[/IMG]

Comment: Hey dude, just simply `\dot{x}` not `\cdot{x}` and for having two dots you can use: `\ddot{x}`

Answer (score 0):

Although this question is years old, I did not find a solution without external libraries. So, here is one. I created a Razor component, but of course you can avoid this by copying its content to your HTML and replace `@ChildContent` by the letter(s) you need the dot above.

#### DottedLetter.razor

```
<span class="d-inline-flex justify-content-center dot-wrapper">
    @ChildContent
</span>

@code {
    [Parameter] public RenderFragment ChildContent { get; set; }
}
```

#### DottedLetter.razor.css

```
.dot-wrapper {
    position: relative;
    width: fit-content;
}

    .dot-wrapper::after {
        position: absolute;
        bottom: 50%;
        content: '\2024'
    }
```

#### Usage in HTML

```
<DottedLetter>Q</DottedLetter>
```

Note, there are many dotted letters available, see [here](https://www.toptal.com/designers/htmlarrows/letters/), but e. g. not `<DottedLetter>Q</DottedLetter>`.